# Jqueryui combobox with disabled options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

Here is my code:

```
<select name='myselect'>
  <option disabled selected>Please Select One</option>
  <option value='1'>java</option>
  <option value='2'>javascript</option>
  <option value='3'>actionscript</option>
  <option value='4' disabled>photoshop</option>
  <option value='5'>ajax</option>
</select>
```

here is the official link for dropdown select combobox
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

here is the link to the pen

https://codepen.io/kaleem78/pen/YjLqXQ

How to handle the disabled option of select dropdown using Combobox(jQueryUI)?

Comment: You don't want to show photoshop because it is disable ?

Comment: @Shree, yes, or anything that prevent user from selecting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `remove` to remove `disable` attribute inside `doucument.ready` (When dom is ready) like below.

```js
$("select option:disabled").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='myselect'>
  <option disabled selected>Please Select One</option>
  <option value='1'>java</option>
  <option value='2'>javascript</option>
  <option value='3'>actionscript</option>
  <option value='4' disabled>photoshop</option>
  <option value='5'>ajax</option>
</select>
```